# Change table to tall format using panda (UNPIVOT)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

I have a table like this

```
   user         company company2 company3 company4
    1           Mac     Lenovo    Hp      null              
    2           Mac       MSI     Sony
```

And using pandas I would like it to be

```
     user    company
     1          Mac
     1          Lenovo
     1          Hp
     2         Mac
```

and so on
Here I tried it but didnt work with pandas pivot.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataframe.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
#dataframe.pivot(index='user', columns='company')
```

Above code doesnt work and gives error.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not particularly specific. Please include the exact error message you see.

Comment: @Metropolis I was thinking the error is pretty stupid so dint want to use it. Sorry will do my best next time

Comment: You can edit your question and include the error message. The exact error is usually very helpful for helping to debug a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [pd.melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
In [211]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='user', value_vars=df.columns.drop('user').tolist())
Out[211]:
   user  variable   value
0     1   company     Mac
1     2   company     Mac
2     1  company2  Lenovo
3     2  company2     MSI
4     1  company3      Hp
5     2  company3    Sony
6     1  company4    null
7     2  company4     NaN
```

or

```
In [213]: pd.melt(df,
                  id_vars='user', value_vars=df.columns.drop('user').tolist(),
                  value_name='Company') \
            .drop('variable',1)
Out[213]:
   user Company
0     1     Mac
1     2     Mac
2     1  Lenovo
3     2     MSI
4     1      Hp
5     2    Sony
6     1    null
7     2     NaN
```

**UPDATE:** dropping NaN's and sorting resulting DF by `user`:

```
In [218]: pd.melt(df,
     ...:         id_vars='user', value_vars=df.columns.drop('user').tolist(),
     ...:         value_name='Company') \
     ...:   .drop('variable',1) \
     ...:   .dropna() \
     ...:   .sort_values('user')
     ...:
Out[218]:
   user Company
0     1     Mac
2     1  Lenovo
4     1      Hp
6     1    null
1     2     Mac
3     2     MSI
5     2    Sony
```

PS if you want to get rid of `null` values - use `df.replace('null', np.nan)` instead of `df`:

```
In [219]: pd.melt(df.replace('null', np.nan),
     ...:         id_vars='user', value_vars=df.columns.drop('user').tolist(),
     ...:         value_name='Company') \
     ...:   .drop('variable',1) \
     ...:   .dropna() \
     ...:   .sort_values('user')
     ...:
Out[219]:
   user Company
0     1     Mac
2     1  Lenovo
4     1      Hp
1     2     Mac
3     2     MSI
5     2    Sony
```

Comment: @Aurora, could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Sorry, Umm nothing changed, the tables are the same

Comment: I am tryin to use the second example of yours, the first one works

Comment: @Aurora, try this: `result = pd.melt(...)`

Comment: Oh yea sorry!! I totally forgot to get the output value haha. Thanks alot Max!

Comment: Sorry I have a problem  again, I noticed only the head elements so I accepted the answer, but the first row result is like this  user 1 ,comapny Mac, then the second row is for user 2 , it dint continue with user 1 :(

Comment: @Aurora, so do you want to sort the result data set by `user`? You can add `.sort_values('user')` to the solution

Comment: Yes! That would be great!

Comment: I added sortvalue('user') but now some of the values are like in different rows and not one by one, could you please edit the answer.

Comment: @Aurora, please check UPDATE - is that what you want?

Comment: yes exactly like that! Now its fine! sorry for the trouble, but you helped me learn something new ^_^

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use `stack` for it (don't know if it is more efficient then `melt`:

```
dataframe.set_index("user").stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True)

user
1       Mac
1    Lenovo
1        Hp
2       MSI
2       Mac
2      Sony
```

Stack essentially pushes the columns to be part of the index (and create `MultiIndex`) - thus, for every column-row combination, you get a row in the new `DataFrame`. That is, the `DataFrame`

```
   C1 C2
0  A  B
1  a  b
```

after `stack()` becomes the `Series`

```
0  C1 A
0  C2 B
1  C1 a
1  C2 b
```

Comment: I tried it but dint actually work properly, could you please edit the answer to follow my example, It would be great!

Comment: I assumed `user` was your index. Try the above version (I added `set_index("user")`)